# UITableView tapgesture behaviour

Tags: swift, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

When I tap on my table view it will trigger `touchesBegan` and `touchesShouldBegin`. However, I also have a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on my view cells and when panning a cell, tapping on other cells won't trigger `touchesShouldBegin`.

The reason I need `touchesShouldBegin` is because I want to stop the touches when a cell is being panned. Is there other methods I can use to do this? I have tried having set `allowsMultipleSelection` to `false` and `true`.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("This will always be printed")
}

override func touchesShouldBegin(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?, in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    print("This will only be printed when no cells are being panned")

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `UITableView`'s `delaysContentTouches` property to `true`.

You can also try to add the a `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and have :

```
extension MyViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```